# "Magento Tax Zones & Rates": how to incorporate store location and price dependencies for Tax Rates

Tags: magento

I am using Magento. I would like someone to confirm the following issue
pertaining to the following configuration screen:

Magento Admin Panel -> Sales -> Tax -> Manage Tax Zones & Rates

1. On this screen, the Country, State/Region, Zip/Post Code, and Rate.

Presumably these correspond to the billing address of the purchaser
(hence not the purchaser's shipping address, and not the store's address).

1. Inc case a store has multiple locations, then the Tax Rates need to
   also incorporate the store's location, as this will affect the rate for
   shipping to a given address. Hence the name of the Tax Rate should
   also include the store's location.
2. Furthermore the Tax Rate can be affected by the total amount charged
   on the product shipped, or, alternatively, the product quantity for the
   shipped product.

I was wondering whether it is better to incorporate, or rather, organize,
such information in the Tax Rule Name or in the Tax Rate Tax Identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Presumably these correspond to the billing address of the purchaser (hence not the purchaser's shipping address, and not the store's address).**

No, this is something you set yourself in System-> Configuration-> Sales Tab -> Tax-> Calculation Settings.

I don't know about the rest of the world but in the UK the decision whether or not to apply sales tax is made on the delivery destination rather than the billing address because the important distinction is  where the goods will be consumed, not where the purchaser resides.

**Inc case a store has multiple locations, then the Tax Rates need to also incorporate the store's location,**

This is correct, but you set the store's location in System-> Configuration-> Sales Tab -> Tax-> Default Tax Destination Calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your information. As to your second answer though, I was wondering about the setting where there is more than one store for example one store per country. Then how do you incorporate such information (the information about which store the item is shipped from)? What is puzzling is that while on the System -> Configuration one can configure the "Current Configuration Scope", which can be Global, Website, or Store View, this drop down does not appear if one of the subcategories of sales is chosen for the page to be displayed.

Comment: Hmm, I've just checked a couple of sites and I can change the configuration scope in those tabs for stores which have multiple websites.  I've checked a site with only one view and I can change the scope down to store view for that too. I'm afriad I am not sure why you can't do that in your store, sorry.