# How change the grand total at Shipping Information step while checkout in Mgento1.9

Tags: php, magento

I am using **Magento 1.9.0.1**. I want to change the `grand total` at `Shipping Information step` while `checkout`.I added new field called `Locality` in  `Shipping Information` step.Depending on the `locality` selected by user, some amount should added to `Grand total` .And the newly changed `grand total should save in db and display in order page in back end`.

I added new field `Locality`.
On change of `locality` field the `grand total` will change.
But I don't know how to change the grand total. Please help me...

I only need to know **How change the grand total at Shipping Information step while checkout.**

Comment: why you want to add some amount to grand total??? you can simply create some tax rules...

Comment: Depending on the Locality selected I want to add extra amount to grand total..How can I do this by code..please..

Comment: by locality you mean states or countries???

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430794/how-to-add-state-wise-tax-charge-without-adding-customer-and-product-class  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576000/magento-tax-zones-rates-how-to-incorporate-store-location-and-price-depende

Comment: @NishantSolanki, locality is a newly added field just like city or landmark

Comment: @NishantSolanki, tax rules not suit for here.

Comment: I think that wont be so simple to do. that will need too much modifications in magento core files. but you can check this answer out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363876/how-to-set-custom-grand-total-before-checkout-process-in-magento

Comment: @next2u: When ever you want to work out with the Grand Total or any changes in the Total of the product at that time you can create one "Observer" for that which will add or subtracts what ever amount you want from the cart total. Hope you can get what i am suggesting to you .

Comment: @NishantSolanki: the demo link in the answer gives nothing..

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia, can you post some code? I don't know how to create/where to create the "Observer"..

Answer (score 0):

Currently working on the similar issue, but can't save totals after it, but the mail code looks like it. config.xml

```
  <global>
    <models>
      <test_example>
        <class>Test_Example_Model</class>
      </test_example>
    </models>

    <events>
      <checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
        <observers>
          <check_totals>
            <class>Test_Example_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>checkTotals</method>
          </check_totals>
        </observers>
      </checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method>
    </events>
  </global>
```

Function of observer

```
public function checkTotals(Varient_Event_Observer $observer)
    {   
        $quote      = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote();
        $grandTotal = '12';

        $quote->setData('grand_total', $grandTotal);
        $quote->setData('base_grand_total', $grandTotal);
        $quote->save();
        }
    }
```

But I stuck on save() method, because it doesn't work somehow